# If the user inputs a position over 5. It is supposed to print `The account number not found`

Tags: python

I am writing a banking application using arrays and functions in python. I am having trouble with the line `if (position>4):
        print("The account number not found!")` Here's my code:

```
NamesArray=[]
AccountNumbersArray=[]
BalanceArray=[]
def PopulateAccounts():
    for position in range(5):
        name = input("Please enter a name: ")
        account = input("Please enter an account number: ")
        balance = input("Please enter a balance: ")
        NamesArray.append(name)
        AccountNumbersArray.append(account)
        BalanceArray.append(balance)
def SearchAccounts():
    accounttosearch = input("Please enter the account number to search: ")
    for position in range(5):
        if (accounttosearch==AccountNumbersArray[position]):
            print("Name is: " +NamesArray[position])
            print(NamesArray[position]+" account has the balance of : $" +str(BalanceArray[position]))
            break
    if (position>4):
        print("The account number not found!")


while True:
    print("**** MENU OPTIONS ****")
    print("Type P to populate accounts")
    print("Type S to search for account")
    print("Type E to exit")
    choice = input("Please enter your choice: ")
    if (choice=="P"):
        PopulateAccounts()
    elif (choice=="S"):
        SearchAccounts()
    elif (choice=="E"):
        print("Thank you for using the program.")
        print("Bye")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid choice. Please try again!")
```

The code works fine, except if the user inputs a position over 5. It has to print `The account number not found!` and then go back to the menu. It goes back to the main menu, but without printing the statement. How can I fix this?

Comment: See [mcve] guidelines -- rather than showing your whole code, an ideal question would have only the shortest code necessary to demonstrate a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to check account to search not position:

```
def SearchAccounts():
    accounttosearch = input("Please enter the account number to search: ")
    for position in range(5):
        if (accounttosearch==AccountNumbersArray[position]):
            print("Name is: " +NamesArray[position])
            print(NamesArray[position]+" account has the balance of : $" +str(BalanceArray[position]))
        break
    if (accounttosearch>4):
        print("The account number not found!")
```

Comment: Eh? Since you're iterating over `range(5)`, the number will *never* be more than `5`. (it will only be `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`). The part of the code the OP is having a problem with is, per their description, somewhere the account number to operate on is coming from *input*.